# Python - apply a formula if a condition is met

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to change a value in a dataframe if the value starts with something.
I am checking to see if the first 4 values are 0.00
If it starts with 0.00 i want to multiply that value by 100
The below formula gives me this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My formula is

```
Total['Rate']=Total['Rate'].apply(lambda x: Total['Rate']*100 if \ 
Total['Rate'].str[:4]=='0.00' else Total['Rate'])
```

Comment: Can you add an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem? Tag `dataframe` - do you mean `pandas.DataFrame`? If so - tag accordingly with `pandas`

Comment: What is reason for compare first 4 values of number by converting to strings? I think it is bad idea, for good performance work only with numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close, the problem is that in your lambda function you're trying to multiply the whole column rather than just the value.

By changing these to x as seen below, you've got it.

```
Total['Rate'] = Total['Rate'].apply(lambda x: x*100 if str(x)[:4]=='0.00' else x, 1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my opinion solution working, but working with numbers like strings is a bit weird, especially if it is slowier. So not recommended your solution.

Comment: @IMiller - Added solution to multiple masks to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to strings is not necessary, better is convert multiplies values to `integers` and compare with `0`:

```
Total = pd.DataFrame(data=[0.001,0.2,5,0.0002],columns=['Rate'])

s = Total['Rate'] * 100
Total['Rate'] = np.where(s.astype(int) == 0, s, Total['Rate'])
print (Total)
   Rate
0  0.10
1  0.20
2  5.00
3  0.02
```

**Details**:

```
print (s)
0      0.10
1     20.00
2    500.00
3      0.02
Name: Rate, dtype: float64

print (s.astype(int))
0      0
1     20
2    500
3      0
Name: Rate, dtype: int32

print (s.astype(int) == 0)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: Rate, dtype: bool
```

**Performance**:

```
Total = pd.DataFrame(data=[0.001,0.2,5,0.0002],columns=['Rate'])
Total = pd.concat([Total] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [296]: %%timeit
     ...: s = Total['Rate'] * 100
     ...: Total['Rate'] = np.where(s.round() == 0, s, Total['Rate'])
     ...: 
2.09 ms ± 119 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [297]: %%timeit
     ...: Total['Rate'] = Total['Rate'].apply(lambda x: x*100 if str(x)[:4]=='0.00' else x, 1)
     ...: 
26.2 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

EDIT: If want set values to multiple masks e.g. negative to `0` use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
Total = pd.DataFrame(data=[0.001,0.2,5,0.0002, -10],columns=['Rate'])

s = Total['Rate'] * 100

mask1 = s.astype(int) == 0
mask2 = Total['Rate'] < 0

Total['Rate'] = np.select([mask1, mask2], [s, 0], default=Total['Rate'])
print (Total)
   Rate
0  0.10
1  0.20
2  5.00
3  0.02
4  0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
Total['Rate']=Total['Rate'].mask(Total['Rate'].str.startswith('0.00'), Total['Rate']*100)
```